# Connecting to Azure Analysis Services using python

Tags: linux, azure, powerbi, azure-analysis-services

I am trying to query my powerbi metadata stored in Azure Analysis services through python.
I have used Nuget package and loaded the dll "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient" to  my root folder (RHEL Linux), when I tried to execute the below program it throws an error (screenshot attached below)

```
from sys import path
path.append('/root/dll/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient')
from pyadomd import Pyadomd
conn='Provider=MSOLAP.7;Data Source=powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/;Initial Catalog=model;User Id=testuser;Password=;'
query = "SELECT DIMENSION_CAPTION AS [DIMENSION] FROM $system.MDSchema_Dimensions"

with Pyadomd(conn) as conn:
    with conn.cursor().execute(query) as cur:
        print(cur.fetchall())
```

Here is the screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this error?  Have you tried googling the "Entry point not found" issue? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/getting-entry-point-not-found-error-message-while/3d39b6f9-757a-4836-92e0-05cf7e2d5fc2

Comment: The error is related to pyadomd package, also I am trying to run this in Linux.

Comment: Got the solution from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/233745/can-adomd-net-core-connect-to-an-ssas-endpoint-fro.html

Comment: @Rajasekar Please post what worked for you as an answer below so it helps others in the community as well.